# Why dynamic link created programmatically is not listed in "Dynamic Links" of Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

When I created the dynamic link manually from Firebase Console then it got listed in "Dynamic Links" section, but when the links are created programmatically then it is not listed in the "Dynamic Links" section of Firebase Console.

These programmatically created links works properly but are not listed.

[Screenshot of Dynamic Links Section in Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlM8F.png)

I have followed this blog for Dynamic links setup in my Flutter App.
Link: https://www.filledstacks.com/post/dynamic-links-in-flutter-a-complete-guide/

Comment: Dynamic Links are only listed in the console when created there. This is AFAIK by design.

Answer (score 5):

This is an intended behavior. Short Dynamic Links created programmatically are designed to be shared peer to peer. If there are multiple clients creating FDL, it's likely that the short links to be displayed on the dashboard will be a long list. This can be challenging to navigate and track created links.

Short Dynamic Links created through Firebase Console on the other hand are more likely to be used in campaigns and makes sense to be tracked on the dashboard.

If you have feedback regarding this function, you can file a feature request here https://firebase.google.com/support